# Get MSAL Interceptor Configuration from API

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

For a Static Web App (SPA) I have configured one endpoint */api/settings*. This endpoint does not require authentication and returns a list of other endpoints that are needed in the application. Now the problem is, these endpoints returned by */api/settings* do require authentication.

In the code bellow, I need to configure `protectedResourceMap` with the response of */api/settings*. I tried to build a factory for the `MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG` provider, but I think it doesn't work because it ends up in a circular dependency.

Does anyone have a solution to create the `protectedResourceMap` from the API response? Another appoach would be to manually append the token when requesting the endpoints, but I couldn't find a way to do that either.

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // ...
  ],
  imports: [
    // ...
    HttpClientModule,
    MsalModule.forRoot(
      new PublicClientApplication({
        auth: {
          clientId: environment.msalClientId,
          authority: environment.msalAuthority,
          redirectUri: '/',
        },
        cache: {
          cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
          storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // Set to true for Internet Explorer 11
        },
      }),
      {
        interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect, // MSAL Guard Configuration
        authRequest: {
          scopes: [environment.msalClientId + '/.default'],
        },
      },
      {
        interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect, // MSAL Interceptor Configuration
        protectedResourceMap: new Map<string, string[]>(),
      }
    ),
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    MsalGuard,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, MsalRedirectComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I am looking for a solution to this problem currently. Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend manually appending auth tokens to apis in your current situation. You didn't specify how you notified your api/settings or how you saved the response in your code. It would be beneficial to provide more guidance if you could share that.